# Set div id in javascript based on modal content

Tags: javascript, html

On my homepage, index.html, I have a div for a rating system like this

```
<div class="srtgs" id="rt_??"></div>
```

Then in my javascript I have a function that generates modal content for each feature in an array, within this I need each modal to have the div above like this

```
<div class="srtgs" id="rt_<feature.properties.name>"></div>
```

I tried to change the id in javascript which works but then on page refresh when it loads the modal it is back to rt_?? so it does not get the correct ratings from the DB

Any help is appreciated cheers

Comment: javascript WILL obviously be temporary fix. you can modify html or make your script load everytime on page load

Comment: @MehulMohan what would be a solution then, rather than a temporary fix, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS function with your code for a div id.

Then Use:

```
<body onload="javascriptFn()">
```

Change "javascriptFn()" to your function name.

Comment: Sorry seems a fairly vague answer